# Why can I edit others' deleted answers?

Tags: bug, edits, deleted-answers

I just hit sweet 10k, so as a curious user, I instantly checked [the famous first question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1/3151675).

To my surprise, the editing function actually worked for deleted answers that were not mine.

[image: Deleted - and edited - answer]

I think this is also visible to others, because the other answer below this question was edited in 2016 and was deleted back in 2008.

Why is this?

Comment: Turn it around: why *shouldn't* you be able to edit posts you can see? What if you felt the post could be improved and undeleted? Then you don't have to wait for it to be undeleted first, you can collaborate on improving the post before casting an undelete vote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The better question is why they could edit a locked question.  That seems like more of a problem.

Comment: Being able to hide highly objectionable NSFW content from 10K eyes is a feature.

Comment: @Servy Only the question is locked there. A locked question does not lock all the answers with it.

Comment: One good reason: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/354885/revisions